# Decrease the size of jdialog

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jdialog

I've to created a custom jdialog but i want it a bit small. It should not have empty space. The following code gives me this:

[image: Gui]

If I decrease the size using setSize, it results into a bad GUI like this:

[image: BadGui]

```
class Find extends JDialog
{
    JPanel f1,f2,f3,rp;
    JLabel fl,filler1,filler2,filler3;
    JTextField ft,fillert;
    JCheckBox mcase;
    JButton fb1,fb2;
    JRadioButton upr,dr;
    ButtonGroup rg;
    public Find()
    {
        setTitle("Find");

        f3 = new JPanel();
        f3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        f3.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

        f1 = new JPanel();
        f1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f1,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        f2 = new JPanel();
        f2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f2,BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        fl = new JLabel("Find what: ");
        ft = new JTextField();

        fb1 = new JButton("  Find  ");
        mcase = new JCheckBox("Match case",false);
        fb2 = new JButton("Cancel");
        rg = new ButtonGroup();
        upr = new JRadioButton("Up");
        dr = new JRadioButton("Down");
        rg.add(upr);
        rg.add(dr);
        rp = new JPanel();
        rp.add(upr);
        rp.add(dr);

        filler1 = new JLabel(" ");
        filler2 = new JLabel(" ");

        f1.add(fl);
        f1.add(ft);
        f1.add(filler1);
        f1.add(fb1);

        f2.add(mcase);
        f2.add(rp);
        //f2.add(filler2);
        //f2.add(fb2);

        f3.add(f1);
        //f3.add(new JLabel());
        f3.add(f2);

        add(f3);
        setSize(400,120);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: What should I do make the JDialog smaller eliminating the empty space at the bottom?

Answer (score 1):

Your **f3** `JPanel` has a `GridLayout` with 3 rows, and the third one is empty .

You only need 2, so try :

```
f3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

OR :

Change the LayoutManager of **f3** to a vertical `BoxLayout`

```
f3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(f3, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

And reduce the height of the `JDialog` :

```
setSize(400,100);
```

Comment: That results into bigger and bulky textfield: [See image](http://imgur.com/oOlk60b)

Answer (score 0):

```
f3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
ft.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250,25));
```

The above changes did the trick!

Comment: Changing the layout parameters has nothing to do with the problem. The parameters are only suggestions. If you only add two components, then the space will be allocated evenly between the two components. What you should be doing is using `pack()` instead of `setSize()`. Then the dialog will display all the components at there preferred size, instead of some arbitrary size that you hard coded.